# Is there a way to count a concat statement?

Tags: mysql

I need to write a query to list the names of all employees (in 1 column) and the number of individuals they supervise.

I have tried using a count in combination with a concat but it won't work and I just don't know how to move on.

```
select 
  concat(Boss.firstName, ' ', Boss.lastName) as 'Boss', 
  concat(supervised.firstName, ' ',supervised.lastName) as supervised, 
  count(supervised.firstName, ' ',supervised.lastName)
from Employees as Boss
left join Employees as supervised on Boss.employeeNumber=supervised.reportsTo;
```

I need the second column to have a numerical value. I would appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add grouping in your query and count the rows for each Boss:

```
select 
  concat(Boss.firstName, ' ', Boss.lastName) as Boss, 
  count(supervised.lastName) counter
from Employees as Boss left join Employees as supervised 
on Boss.employeeNumber = supervised.reportsTo
group by concat(Boss.firstName, ' ', Boss.lastName)
```

Comment: Count should probably be on something from `supervised` that normally can't be null, like `reportsTo`, shouldn't it? Otherwise people that supervise no one will have counts of 1.

Comment: Not sure, but since it is  a left join it can return nulls, so I edited to count nulls as zeros. I suppose not all employees are bosses!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT concat(e1.firstname, ' ', e1.lastname) supervisor,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM employees e2
               WHERE e2.reportsto = e1.employeenumber) supervised_count
       FROM employees e1;
```